# How do I make the diff view in GitKraken take 100% of screen width

Tags: gitkraken

When I view the diff in my GitKraken, I would like it to cover 100% of the screen spacee:
[image]

If there is no way available, is there a way to let Gitkraken launch an external diff app like *Kaleidoscope*?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible to completely remove the panel you refer to as "this guy" in your image. But at the top right of "this guy" there is a button with which you can pin "this guy" to the right so you gain 100% screen *height* instead of 100% screen *width*. I guess this isn't what you really want, so I have to answer your follow-up-question.

In the settings (open either with a click on the gear symbol at the top right of the GitKraken window or with Ctrl+P and type "Settings" and Enter) you can find under the "General" section (opens by default when opening the settings) the option "External Diff Tool". I didn't try this option yet but I guess this is where you can set Kaleidoscope as your diff tool.